# Spreading Extended Type Props into Typescript Interface

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I have the following interfaces:

```js
interface ButtonProps {
  name: string;
}

interface IconButtonProps {
  name: string;
  icon: string;
}
```

I'm trying to create the type for the following component:

```js
<MyGenericComponent component={button} name="button">...
<MyGenericComponent component={iconButton} name="icon-button" icon="icon">...
```

The idea is that I'm unable to type the interface that would represent `MyGenericComponentProps` so that it can accept a react component in the `component` prop as long as all other props given to it are those that the given component would accept!

Something like this:

```js
interface MyGenericComponentProps<T> extends T {
  component: React.FC<T>;
}
```

...where `T` above can be `ButtonProps` or `IconButtonProps`. I know I cannot extend `T` because it's unknown statically, but then how do I ensure that the rest of the props given are those of either `ButtonProps` or `IconButtonProps`?

UPDATE: here's the component definition after answer:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { ButtonProps, IconButtonProps } from '@material-ui/core';

type MyGenericComponentProps<T> = {
    component: React.FC<T>;
} & {
    [key in keyof T]: T[key];
};

const MyGenericComponent = <T extends object>({ component, ...props }: MyGenericComponentProps<T>) => {
    // ... more code here
    const Component = component;
    return <Component {...props} />;
};

export default MyGenericComponent;
```

Answer (score 2):

If it doesn't make sense what kind of TS entity will be used (type or interface) then you can type it as a type instead of an interface:

```
type MyGenericComponentProps<T> = {
  component: React.FC<T>;
} & {
  [key in keyof T]: T[key];
}
```

[UPDATE]:

You need to modify and even simplify some fragments:

```
type MyGenericComponentProps<T> = {
  component: React.FC<T>;
  props: T; 
}

const MyGenericComponent = <T extends object>({component: Component, props}: MyGenericComponentProps<T>) => {
  // ... more code here
  return <Component {...props}/>;
};
```

Comment: Thank you. The problem is when trying to implement `MyGenericComponent` there after, I get the following error: Type ‘Pick<MyGenericComponentProps<T>, Exclude<keyof T, "component">>' is not assignable to type ‘IntrinsicAttributes & T & { children?: ReactNode; }’.
  Type ‘Pick<MyGenericComponentProps<T>, Exclude<keyof T, "component">>' is not assignable to type ‘T’.
    ‘Pick<MyGenericComponentProps<T>, Exclude<keyof T, "component">>' is assignable to the constraint of type ‘T’, but ‘T’ could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint ‘MyGenericComponentProps’.ts(2322)

Comment: FYI, what I'm trying to do inside `MyGenericComponent` is `let Component = component` then `<Component {...props} />` whereby I get the error above.

Comment: Please, show how you define ```MyGenericComponent```.

Comment: I just updated the question to share the full definition. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thank you, but this way I do not have `props` as a part of the interface properties itself. I do not want to pass props in a `props` object, but directly.

Answer (score 1):

```
interface ButtonProps {
  name: string;
}

interface IconButtonProps extends ButtonProps{
  icon?: string;
}
```

and

```
interface MyGenericComponentProps<IconButtonProps>{
  component: React.FC<IconButtonProps>;
}
```

do not know about react, but with typescript you can do extend interfaces and declare optional properties. Then this would accept ButtonProps and IconButtonProps